# I AM Implementing FAQ Using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So All the Question and Answer I Already stored in Table using SQL Server.
And It Perfectly Fetching All the Question with Answer.
Below image link is my actual FAQ user Interface all Question Fetch Correctly from table.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlhtU.png
and When Click on 1 Question it Toggle and Show Answer Exactly below to the Question.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw2N.png
But Actual Problem occur when i click to 2 question it toggle or directing me to 1st question Answer rather than showing to its answer.

Below code of the Design page

```
<section class="faq-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- ***** FAQ Start ***** -->
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">

                <div class="faq-title text-center pb-3">
                    <h2>FAQ</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <div class="faq" id="accordion">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" id="faqHeading-1">
                                <div class="mb-0">
<h5 class="faq-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faqCollapse-1" data-aria-expanded="true" data-aria-controls="faqCollapse-1">
                             <span class="badge"></span>@item.FAQ_question
                                </h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
   <div id="faqCollapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="faqHeading-1" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                <p> @item.FAQ_answer</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And
Below code is View Source Page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FaqList - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/FAQ/Faq1">AddFAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/FAQ/FaqList">FaqList</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    


<link href="/Content/FAQstylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h2>FaqList</h2>





    <section class="faq-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- ***** FAQ Start ***** -->
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    
                    <div class="faq-title text-center pb-3">
                        <h2>FAQ</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                        <div class="faq" id="accordion">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header" id="faqHeading-1">
                                    <div class="mb-0">
                                        <h5 class="faq-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faqCollapse-1" data-aria-expanded="true" data-aria-controls="faqCollapse-1">
                                            <span class="badge"></span>How to reset Password?                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="faqCollapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="faqHeading-1" data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <p> Click on Forget Password button and Enter new password and click on reset.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
                        <div class="faq" id="accordion">
    
    
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header" id="faqHeading-1">
                                    <div class="mb-0">
                                        <h5 class="faq-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faqCollapse-1" data-aria-expanded="true" data-aria-controls="faqCollapse-1">
                                            <span class="badge"></span>How to do Registration?                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="faqCollapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="faqHeading-1" data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <p> vjjkegenve                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
                        <div class="faq" id="accordion">
    
    
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header" id="faqHeading-1">
                                    <div class="mb-0">
                                        <h5 class="faq-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faqCollapse-1" data-aria-expanded="true" data-aria-controls="faqCollapse-1">
                                            <span class="badge"></span>How to do Assesment?                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
   <div id="faqCollapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="faqHeading-1" data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                   <p> cbwkc bckjbckwc kbvkjcvkwc kbckwjbcjkw </p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
                        <div class="faq" id="accordion">
    
    
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header" id="faqHeading-1">
                                    <div class="mb-0">
                                        <h5 class="faq-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#faqCollapse-1" data-aria-expanded="true" data-aria-controls="faqCollapse-1">
                                            <span class="badge"></span>How to view Ebooks?                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                        </h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="faqCollapse-1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="faqHeading-1" data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <p> hb wv hjbvhwsbv jkvbjhbv bkwbcvkwc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create data-target="#faqCollapse-1"  and  id ="faqCollapse-1" dynamically.

Update your code as data-target="#faqCollapse-"+@item.Id   and id ="faqCollapse-"+@item.Id

Here Item.Id  should be any unique field on the item